# Biblatex use value from a different field as main title

Tags: biblatex

For a paper I am writing I am using the *geschichtsfrkl* style, which expects the booktitle fields to be called maintitle for @inreference and @incollection entries.

Zotero (and all my bib files for that matter) use the standard biblatex format, where the title of a book chapter or encyclopedia entry is booktitle and I would like to keep it that way.

Is there a way to keep the bibliography files the way they are and reconfigure the style to use the booktitle field for maintitle? I expected `\DeclareFieldAlias{maintitle}{booktitle}` to yield that behaviour, but it seems I am misunderstanding this command.

For example I expect this result when declaring citing an @inreference entry in the example below:

*Haefele, H. F. / Gschwind, Ch.: Art. „Notker I. (Balbulus, "der Stammler")“,
in: Lexikon des Mittelalters 6 (1999), 1289–1290*

This is what I get instead:
*Haefele, H. F. / Gschwind, Ch.: Art. „Notker I. (Balbulus, "der Stammler")“, in: (1999), 1289–1290.*

(Note the difference is the missing title after **in:**)

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[style=german]{csquotes}
\usepackage{helvet} %helvetica font

\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=4cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=geschichtsfrkl, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldAlias{maintitle}{booktitle}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@inreference{haefeleNotkerBalbulusStammler-1999,
  title = {Notker I. (Balbulus, "der Stammler")},
  booktitle = {Lexikon des Mittelalters},
%  maintitle = {Lexikon des Mittelalters}, %this works
  author = {Haefele, H. F. and family=Gschwind, given=Ch., given-i={{Ch}}},
  date = {-1999},
  origdate = {1977},
  series = {Brepolis Medieval Encyclopaedias - Lexikon des Mittelalters Online},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {1289--1290},
  publisher = {{J.B. Metzler,}},
  location = {{Stuttgart}},
  langid = {ngerman},
  volumes = {10},
}

@incollection{goetzStaatlichkeitHerrschaftsordnungUnd2000,
  title = {Staatlichkeit, Herrschaftsordnung Und Lehnswesen Im Ostfränkischen Reich Als Forschungsproblem},
  booktitle = {Il {{Feudalesimo}} Nell'{{Alto Medioevo}}},
%  maintitle = {Il {{Feudalesimo}} Nell'{{Alto Medioevo}}}, %this works
  author = {Goetz, Hans-Werner},
  date = {2000},
  pages = {85--143},
  url = {http://opac.regesta-imperii.de/id/160891},
  uniqueid = {160891},
  keywords = {9. Jahrhundert,Deutschland,Europa,Feudalsystem,Frankenreich,Goetz,Hans-Werner (1947-),Reichsgeschichte,Staat,Staatlichkeit},
  file = {/home/chris/Historische Wissenschaften/Zotero/storage/SJANFAN9/Goetz - 2000 - Staatlichkeit, herrschaftsordnung und lehnswesen i.PDF}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\fullcite{goetzStaatlichkeitHerrschaftsordnungUnd2000} \\
Empty line \\
\fullcite{haefeleNotkerBalbulusStammler-1999}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a source mapping? As I read the documentation, the command you've used declares an alias for the *format* rather than the data of the field.

Comment: I am not sure, I have to look that up. I haven't been that deep into biblatex yet.
I had the same thought, but I was not sure

Comment: I just tried it out and using a \DeclareSourcemap seems to solve the issue. I will test this some more tomorrow and post an answer, if that truly works.

Comment: I'm pleased if it helps. If not, maybe update your question with what you tried. I was really going by what I've seen in answers by the resident Biblatex expert (but I did look it up before putting it in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by cfr I found the relevant section in the biblatex documentation.

Sec. 4.5.3 Dynamic Modification of Data has an example on how to copy the value of one field to another, unless the other field already exists.

This was exactly what I needed, as it works just fine for me to copy the content of `booktitle`to `maintitle`.

The code I used was this:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=booktitle]
      \step[fieldset=maintitle, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```